# Confusing about CUPS and Samba for my print server?

Tags: networking, server, printing, samba

I want to setup my lubuntu desktop as a print server. Most clients are Windows7/10 and some clients are linux (and might be Android and iOS too).

After I googling I found some tutorials use CUPS or Samba or both.

Please tell me, Should I use CUPS and/or Samba ? and Why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CUPS, aka **C**ommon **U**nix **P**rinting **S**ystem, is a program made by Apple in order to unify printing system for all Unix (and -like) OSes, including MacOS, FreeBSD, Linux, ... You can configure CUPS using a web page which is fairly easy, as it doesn't necessarly require the use of the command line.

Samba is, as far as I'm concerned a network file sharing application/protocol. I haven't heard of the fact that it's able to print and scan files. After a little research on the net and I found that Samba uses CUPS as a backend to setup printers.

My advice for you is to go with CUPS as it's, in most cases easier.
Note that you may need to download a driver for your printer if it's not supported natively. Refer to your manifacturer website in that case.

Comment: It's seem CUPS is enough to makes Windows and Linux clients able to print to (using http://ip:631/printers/printer_name). And Samba is a front-end and just makes printers visible on windows network devices(not sure)

Comment: Ubuntu have long supplied this guide to network printing; would it be helpful? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkPrintingWithUbuntu

Comment: @pdc Ubuntu have many very good guides but problem is my primary language is not an english language. :)

Comment: would Google translate be able to help you translate to your favoured language? Many find it very helpful

Comment: Both the SMB/CIFS protocol as well as its implementation *Samba* have supported network printing since their initial releases. -1